# Why do some functions from my contract end up in the ABI while others don't?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, greeter, abi

Using the [greeter example](https://ethereum.org/greeter), The original contracts is written with 4 methods: mortal(), kill(), greeter(), and greet().

Why then when I look at the mined contract does it show me an ABI of:

```
{
  address: "0xaa159b9af634c040e1853fee9dcff12bd6f58772",
  allEvents: function(),
  greet: function(),
  kill: function()
}
```

Are some of these just special built in keywords that act differently? 'mortal()' and 'kill()' seem to have the exact same semantic structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`greeter` and `mortal` are constructors, and like in other languages, only callable once, during instantiation.

Comment: Oh I see, because they have the same name as the class, so they are automatically the constructor.

Comment: Right.  By the way it's fine to leave answers unaccepted to give them time and if you're interested in other answers and explanations, but try not to forget to accept those that you're happy with :)